# how to use custom SMTP configuration in laravel

Tags: laravel, swiftmailer, laravel-mail

i'm trying to send email with custom SMTP configuration (not in the `.env` file)

[image]

what i did try:

```php
        Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.host', $emailConfig->MAIL_HOST);
        Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.port', $emailConfig->MAIL_PORT);
        Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.encryption', $emailConfig->email);
        Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.username', $emailConfig->email);
        Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.password', $emailConfig->password);

        Config::set('mail.from.address', $emailConfig->MAIL_FROM_EMAIL);
        Config::set('mail.from.name', $emailConfig->MAIL_FROM_NAME);

         $user = (object)[
                'email' => $item,
                'name' => substr($item, 0, strpos($item, '@')),
            ];

            if ($i % $mailsCount == 0)$count++;
            if ($user){
                $thisBody = ElzahabyDynamicLaravelString($user,$body,$this->sign);
                $thisSubject = ElzahabyDynamicLaravelString($user,$subject,$this->sign);
                $when = Carbon::now()->addMinutes($every*$count);

                Mail::to($user)
                    ->later($when,new EmailForQueuing($user,$thisBody,$thisSubject,$request->emailTemplate));
            }
```

but i got an error:
`Swift_TransportException: Cannot send message without a sender address in`

Answer (score -1):

Have u set configuration of email in .env file?
Like this :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```